# Not able to bind data to Highcharts in Angular 8

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am new the Highcharts. I am not able to to bind data to series property of Highcharts.

```
constructor(private _httpClientRequestService: HttpClientRequestService, private _toastrService: ToastrService) {
    this._httpClientRequestService.getAllData('http://localhost:62297/api/Dashboard/GetDashboardRoles').subscribe(  
      (Response: any) => {
      this.seriesOptions = Response;   
      console.log(this.seriesOptions);  
    },
    error => {
      this._toastrService.error('Error',error.message);       
    });       
}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.createGraph(); 
  }

 createGraph(){
 this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: 'silver',
        plotBorderWidth: 2,
        plotShadow: true,
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in October, 2019'
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
          }
        }
      },
      
      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        type: undefined,
        // data: [{
        //   name: 'Chrome',
        //   y: 61.41          
        // }, {
        //   name: 'Internet Explorer',
        //   y: 11.84
        //}]
        
        data: this.seriesOptions
        
      }]    
    }
```

}

Data Fetched from Web API is:
[
{
"name": ".Net Developer",
"y": 1
},
{
"name": "DBA",
"y": 1
},
{
"name": "JAVA",
"y": 1
},
{
"name": "Other",
"y": 1
}
]

Comment: provide minimal reproducible code.

Comment: the data fetched is from Web API as follows: [
    {
        "name": ".Net Developer",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "DBA",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "JAVA",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Other",
        "y": 1
    }
]

Comment: If i keep hardcoded values like the commented code in my code snipped, it works properly.

Comment: Please state your actual question, problem and any error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood where the problem is, as you can see in my question this.createGraph() is inside ngOnInit(). I moved the calling of the graph inside the constructor i.e where i am calling the Web.API to fetch data. Bellow is the working code.

```
constructor(private _httpClientRequestService: HttpClientRequestService, private _toastrService: ToastrService) {
    this._httpClientRequestService.getAllData('http://localhost:62297/api/Dashboard/GetDashboardRoles').subscribe(  
      (Response: any) => {
      this.seriesOptions = Response;      
      this.createGraph() 
    },
    error => {
      this._toastrService.error('Error',error.message);       
    });       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example here:

```
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        type: undefined,
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41
          },
          {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-1zxy6e

Comment: the hard coded values works properly. but if i get the data from web.api, then it does not work as follows: [
    {
        "name": ".Net Developer",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "DBA",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "JAVA",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Other",
        "y": 1
    }
]